# Year format validation using rfc2822 and iso8601

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, datetime-format

I am checking date time validation using `rfc2822` and `iso8601` on

```
value = 2222022-06-23 04:54:44 +0000
```

When we check **Time.rfc2822(value)** or **Time.iso8601(value)** it is not validating year which is invalid in the above case and not throwing any error.
Can someone help me with how to validate the year?

Answer (score 0):

```rb
t = "2222022-06-23 04:54:44 +0000"

Time.rfc2822(t)
=> ArgumentError: not RFC 2822 compliant date: "2222022-06-23 04:54:44 +0000"

Time.iso8601(t)
=> ArgumentError: invalid xmlschema format: "2222022-06-23 04:54:44 +0000"
```

The issue might be related to the provided value not honoring an existing time format. In the example `2222022-06-23 04:54:44 +0000` you provide, what is the meaning of 2222022?

A valid time format will be correctly parsed as follows:

```rb
t = "2022-06-23 04:54:44 +0000"
Time.parse(t)

=> "2022-06-23 04:54:44 +0000"

Time.parse(t).year
=> 2022
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.
We are expecting to raise error when we pass invalid year format which is `2222022`

Comment: Added in another example, which does raise an `ArgumentError` when an incorrect time format is being passed. What other validation are you looking for?